# GNU make and nmake: computed names with multiple values

Tags: makefile, nmake, gnu-make

[GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Computed-Names.html#Computed-Names) describes usage of computed names as follows:

```
VAR1 := 5
VARX := VAR1
$(info $((VARX)))
```

Output: `5`

How to use computed name with multiple values inside?

```
VAR1 := 5
VAR2 := 7
VARY := VAR1 VAR2

$(info ???(VARY))
```

So that output would be `5 7`?

Does NMake have similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

For GNU-make:

```
$(foreach item,$(VARY),$($(item)))
```